# python version piped to grep returns code 1

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want to check the current version of python is the one I expect in a bash script.

```
python --version | grep --quiet 'Python 2.7.12 :: Continuum Analytics'
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "python version ok"
fi
```

But the grep command always returns 1, instead of 0, even when I get a good match, even with a simple `grep 'Python'`.  To check it, `echo "${PIPESTATUS[1]}"` Returns `1`

If I pipe some other output to grep, it works as expected, for instance:

```
echo 'Python 2.7.12 :: Continuum Analytics' | grep --quiet 'Python 2.7.12 :: Continuum Analytics'
```

This works properly, and `echo "${PIPESTATUS[1]}"` Returns `0`

What is going wrong with the `python --version` command piped to grep?  how can we fix it?

Comment: Replace `|` by `2>&1 |`.

Comment: @Cyrus that did the trick, but why? Also, what lead you from my issue, piping output to grep, to thinking about Redirecting stderr/stdout?

Comment: For more information I suggest to take a look at: [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)

Answer (score -1):

Try using grep's `-c, --count` option;

```
count=$(python --version 2>&1 | grep -c 'Python 2.7.12 :: Continuum Analytics')
if [ $count == 1 ]; then
    echo "python version ok"
fi
```